# I accidentally deleted Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, uninstall

I have a Lenovo laptop dual booted to Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.
I was on Ubuntu and using `Unity` desktop. I wanted to uninstall the `KDE` I had installed few days ago, so I purged `kubuntu-desktop` and the packages related to `KDE`. This created a lot of unmet dependencies, so I ran `sudo apt autoremove` as suggested.

I logged out to check if KDE was effectively removed and I got a black screen with a blinking cursor. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and successfully entered the console. I thought I only uninstalled the GUI. After that I rebooted and the `GRUB2` boot loader only showed these two entries:

```
Windows Boot Loader (on /dev/sda1)
System settings
```

instead of these four:

```
Ubuntu
Windows Boot Loader (on /dev/sda1)
Advanced options for Ubuntu
System settings
```

So now I cannot use Ubuntu anymore.

Does this mean I completely uninstalled Ubuntu or can I recover it?
In the latter case how can I recover it?
In the former case how come `GRUB2` is still the default boot loader and was not removed? And most important how do I access my Ubuntu partition? I don't mind losing the files on the Ubuntu partition more than I mind having a partition I cannot use.

I can give more information if needed.
Please help me shed light on what occurred. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT #1:**
I haven't tried using a bootable USB so far. I will update as soon as I get one. Anyway I think I'm reinstalling the whole thing...

Comment: What do you mean by k-related packages? All packages starting with "k" ? Secondly, you can access your files through an ubuntu bootable usb which you can make from an ISO with a program called etcher on any OS.

Comment: Thirdly your history from apt is logged in /var/log/apt/history.log so you can trace back your steps. Last: You would neet to use chroot to enter your system for a "save" but I´m thinking you should reinstall as you mention you dont mind loosing your files.. We´re talking minutes of reinstall vs hours of backtracking (Which some consider fun :), So if you want to go the hard way, get /var/log/apt/history.log so we can help you figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.
2. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1
3. Use fdisk utility to list the partitions on a device.

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

Suppose it informs that `/` is `/dev/sda4` and EFI system is '/dev/sda1', continue running:

```
sudo -i    
umount /dev/sda4
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
umount /dev/sda1
mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

In the open file paste these lines:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Control + O, save file. Control + X, close nano. Continue running:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop aptitude deborphan grub-efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi  /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
update-grub
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(kubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get -f install
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
exit
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/dev/pts
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt
reboot
```